# styles to TouchableNativeFeedback

Tags: css, react-native

I am using translate on View inside the TouchableNativeFeedback. But after using translate css the upper part of view is not clickable. Can I give translate css to TouchableNativeFeedback also.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={this._onButtonPress}>
        <View style={styles.app}></View>
      </TouchableNativeFeedback>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  app: {
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    transform: [{ translateY: 25 }]
  }
});
```

I tried giving style to that. But I don't think it accepts that.

React-native version: "0.61.2"

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about some margins or padding.
From the official documentation:

Transforms are style properties that will help you modify the appearance and position of your components using 2D or 3D transformations. However, once you apply transforms, the layouts remain the same around the transformed component hence it might overlap with the nearby components. You can apply margin to the transformed component, the nearby components or padding to the container to prevent such overlaps.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/transforms

Comment: Then how can I work around that

Comment: I don't know which visual result are you going to achieve, can you share your UI screenshot with a place where you have a problem?